# How'd I populate a variable with a comma separated string that comes from foreach loop?

Tags: php, arrays

Suppose I have an array of data like this:

```
array:2 [
  0 => array:2 [
    "id" => 7539
    "os" => "Android"
  ]
  1 => array:2 [
    "id" => 7540
    "os" => "iOS"
  ]
]
```

I want to grab the `id` values only and place them in a variable that's comma separated (i.e `$var = "7539,7540";`) using a `foreach()` loop but for some reason - my code below outputs just the first value in an array (not an individual value).

How can I fix this so that both values are comma separated in a separate variable?

```
$var = "";

foreach($dataSet as $data) {
    $var = explode(",", $data['id']);
}
dd($var);
```

Output:

```
array:1 [
  0 => "7539"
]
```

Comment: I'd just use something like `$var .= "," . $data['id'];` unless you can do something with `implode()`. You'll need to check whether `$var` already has something in it, or just remove the leading comma at the end of the loop.

Comment: @droopsnoot yeah I tried using `implode()`, it didn't work :(.

Comment: you can use this.
`foreach($dataSet as $data) {
    $var .=",".$data['id'];
}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current code doesn't work because you are setting `$var` on each iteration of the `foreach`. You can use string concatenation however arrays can be a bit more concise and give you the opportunity to re-use the data:

```
$ids = array(); //emtpy array to hold the values
foreach($dataSet as $data) {
    $ids[] = $data['id']; //append the `id` to the array
}

$var = implode(',', $ids); //join the ids into a string with a comma as the separator
```

This can also be done using `array_column` if you don't need to loop:

```
$var = implode(',', array_column($dataSet, 'id')); //7539,7540
```

Here is a working example: https://3v4l.org/WNMLX

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with the `implode` method of Collections:

```
collect($dataSet)->implode('id', ',')
```

Or you can also use the Collection methods `pluck` and `join`:

```
collect($dataSet)->pluck('id')->join(',')
```

[Laravel 8.x Docs - Collections - Available Methods](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-implode) - `implode`

[Laravel 8.x Docs - Collections - Available Methods](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-pluck) - `pluck`

[Laravel 8.x Docs - Collections - Available Methods](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-join) - `join`

Comment: You may like to move your answer to the canonical target.  I am doing a major clean up of "implode array column" questions.